# Ratio between bounded function and unbounded function is a bounded function

Tags: calculus, functions

Is the ratio between a bounded function and an unbonded function a bounded function? By doing some example it seems yes ($\sin(x)/x $), but i don't know how to prove that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Take $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$, for instance.

Comment: Hi @JosèCarlosSantos thank you for the counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$$

Then the value of $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$$
is not the same for every $f, g$, and is dependent on the type of convergence exhibited by them.

José's great example illustrates this perfectly with yours.

We have that, close to $0$, $\sin(x)\approx x$ (both linear convergence), so $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1$. On the contrary, $x^2$ exhibits much faster quadratic convergence, so $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}\to\infty$.

Comment: Hello @RhysHughes, your clarification is very useful.